# Нужно отправить сообщение всем пользователям, как это сделать?

Tags: php, mysql

Не знаю, как объяснить, но попробую. 
У меня есть таблица "users", там содержится вся информация о пользователях, есть таблица "pm" - сообщения, как сделать так, чтобы при отправке сообщения оно отправилось сразу всем? (При отправке использую:

```
INSERT INTO pm (to,author,time,title,content) VALUES ($to,$author,$sendtime,$title,$message);
```

Мне, например, не удобно каждый раз лезть в код и менять количество пользователей... Можете помочь? Хочется чтоб по нажатию на кнопку "отправить" отправлялись сообщения всем пользователям, то есть одно сообщение несколько раз (**в зависимости от количества пользователей**) дублировалось и изменялся только получатель. Пример:

```
INSERT INTO pm (to,author,time,title,content) VALUES ('92','1','21:18','title','message');
```

и, если 92-ой пользователь не последний, то сообщение отправляется 93, 94 и так далее...
Скорее всего объяснил непонятно, но по другому не могу :(
Желательно готовый код :)

Comment: "Желательно готовый код" - ну надо же было в конце все испортить!

Comment: @Igor объяснений мне вряд ли хватит... Поэтому и прошу готовый код, увы... :(

Comment: @Igor он был близок)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте выборку ID пользователей из таблицы users и вставьте их вместе с остальными необходимыми полями (в одном запросе, никакого дополнительного кода на php не надо):

```
INSERT INTO pm (to,author,time,title,content)
 SELECT user_id,$author,$sendtime,$title,$message
   FROM users
```